# A = [1,2,3]; Give a subset S ⊆ A x A but S must not be X x Y for any subsets X, Y ⊆ A

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I did A x A and the result was [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]

I also tried X x Y keeping in mind that the subsets are pairs: X = [a, b]; Y = [a', b']

X x Y = [ (a,b), (a',b), (a, b'), (a',b')]

And i stated that any S which has 2 pairs as subsets must be a solution if one of those isnt (1,1), (2,2), (3,3).
So S can be for example (1,2), (1,3).

Is this correct ? Thanks a lot

Comment: $S=\{1\}\times\{2,3\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not correct since $S=\{1\} \times \{2,3\}$. Take $S=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$ instead. If $S=A\times B$ then $1$ and $2$ both belong to $A$ and $2$ and $3$ belong to $B$. So we must have $(1,3) \in S$ a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, you're right, so the last step i should've done is S = A x B so i can see if there is any option that can equal my subset. Thanks